# MSI deploying database and stuff

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

1. Can i make msi or smth like that, to install database on existing server.
   I know how to make sql script for database, but its not cool.
2. Can i configure MSI, to show for example some pictures of my company in installation procces, any related link apprisiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can i make msi or smth like that, to install database on existing server.
```

Yes, you can. There are two approaches:

1. Write a custom action which connects to your server and runs an SQL script that creates the database. This is complicated but free.
2. Use a commercial setup authoring tool which supports SQL scripts. It's much easier, but you need to purchase a license.

> Can i configure MSI, to show for
>   example some pictures of my company in
>   installation procces

Yes, they are called billboards. The native MSI billboards support is very limited, so I recommend an [external UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335354/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-msi-in-wix) solution.

If you want a free solution, you can try [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It supports both external UI and SQL scripts. These features will need some work, but they are doable.

Let me know if you want some recommendation for commercial tools.