# How can I combine three installation files into one installation file?

Tags: wix

I have a redistributable package installation file, a flash installation file, and an exe installation file.

I want to create a file that combines these three into one and installs them all at once.

From what I searched for, I know you can use advanced installer and wix.

However, the advanced installer is difficult to use because it requires a license.

I'm trying to use wix, a free program, but I'm running out of information.

Does anyone know a tutorial or how to combine three files?

I am a foreigner and have trouble communicating. please understand.

Comment: What is the overall goal? Is this for internal corporate use or general distribution? What kind of product is it? Does it involve server components? Please update with some more information. [WiX's Burn feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892350/129130) should allow you to install both MSI files, setup.exe and a few other file types. It is a launcher, downloader, bootstrapper kind of thing.

Comment: You probably want to use the WiX bootstrapper. It can install alk your prerequisites, followed by your application's msi/exe

Comment: You can also try this:  https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html