# How to make rich GUI design fow WiX(Windows Installer XML) dialog?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using WiX for make installer for any product. But I don't want to use default UI dialog which is using in WiX. How to improvise UI of a installer ? Is there any tool for designing UI for a installer with highly customize ?

Comment: See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570134/write-a-wpf-wix-installer/9572763#9572763

Answer (score 1):

Rich GUI is done in bootstrapper (aka. chainer). Chainers are made in tool called Burn (B is for bootstrap). I'm not all that familiar with it, but it was supposed to replace all the GUI available by Windows Installer that you can set in .msi files. This GUI is restrictive, and suitable only for simplest tasks, so the idea is to build .msi only as a database file that is to be consumed by Windows Installer to actually install something, and transfer all the GUI to bootstrapper.

Comment: Yes, Dialecticus...there are lots of restriction while making UI for installer using WiX. But solution is there. Microsoft used WiX for their Visual Studio and MS office installer. They overcome UI restriction and presented a good looking UI for installer. I want just that...How it will be possible, using any rich tool or some other way..?

Comment: @Anudeep, see my comment under your initial post. Microsoft did it by creating a custom bootstrapper application. Like Dialecticus said, the bootstrapper has all the UI. WiX allows you to create your own UI over top of their bootstrapper engine, Burn.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've come across is [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/), although it seems buggy and may have been abandoned.  Still, it allows you to do basic UI design of the WiX dialogs.

Comment: Yaa..that is always available to us. But I want something new. High customization on UI dialog on behalf of looking.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across something called [Wix#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804584/Wixsharp-WixSharp-UI-Extensions). It lets you make custom dialogs using a Winforms-like designer.

I know it's **9 years** later, but if it helps, great.